# How to keep textbox text values after ModelState.IsValid return false?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How can I keep values of input type text values after ModelState.IsValid return false.
My captcha functionality is depend on model state. if I enter wrong captcha ModelState.IsValid will return false. So how can i keep my textbox values after ModelState.IsValid return false.

```
My Model
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

My view

```
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
     <input class="form-control" maxlength="50" id="FirstName" asp-for="FirstName" autocomplete="off" placeholder="First Name" type="text" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" required="">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
     <input class="form-control" maxlength="50" id="LastName" asp-for="LastName" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" required="">
  </div>
</div>
```

My Controller

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)     //returning false 
 {
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted the key-value pairs in ModelState Dictionary，you could pass the entity to the View  method Like`return View(entity)`

If you didn't modified the key-value pairs in ModelState Dictionary,it would retrun ModelState[key].RawValue to fill the input box depend on  name attribute (name="key")

Comment: I already returned the viewmodel. but still facing the same,

Comment: Oh,sorry I once misunderstood that you've cleared the ModelState Dictionary,could show what your controller received and RawValue properties when you debug?